# Polymer compute and set property value with this.set() not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to display a list of names in an array through a custom element name `x-names`. The code to display the list of names is as follows:

```
<x-names names="{{names}}"></x-names>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[names]]" as="name">
  <h5>Name: [[name]]</h5>
</template>
```

The `x-names` element is defined as follows:

```
<dom-module id="x-names">
  <template>
    <akc-meta-query key="names" value="{{_namesObject}}"></akc-meta-query>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'x-names',

      properties: {

        names: {
          type: Array,
          computed: '_namesObjectToArray(_namesObject)',
          value: [],
          notify: true
        },

        _namesObject: {
          type: Object
        }
      },

      _namesOjbectToArray: function(obj) {
        if (obj) {
          var keys = Object.keys(obj);
          this.set('names', keys);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The keys of the object are the names, so I simply want to get the keys and set that array to the `names` property, *but*, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property names of #<x-names> which has only a getter
```

I'm fairly new to Polymer, so I'm sure it's a quick fix, but it's 100% escaping me. I've looked through the documentation (which I'm still getting used to), and have tried a couple other ways with no luck:

`this.names = keys` and `return keys` don't generate an error, but they also doesn't reflect the names to the `dom-repeat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't set in the function you defined for `computed`. This function should return the values

```
  _namesOjbectToArray: function(obj) {
    if (obj) {
      return keys = Object.keys(obj);
    } 
     // else {
     // return [];
     // }
  }
```

Comment: I had tried `return keys` before, but it didn't work. Maybe I had messed up a binding elsewhere when I tried it, but now it works as expected. Thanks for the answer!